# Less - How to replace integer with a string?

Tags: less

I have a LESS variable:
`@columns: 12;`

I create a dynamic class name out of it:
`.one-@{columns} {} // returns .one-12 {}`

How do I replace the 12 with a string "twelfth"

### Pseudo Code

`.one-@{replace(columns, "twelfth")} {}`

The result will be `.one-twelfth {}`

Advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry but why not set the words as the variable value? Are you trying to do some sort of number - word conversion here?

Comment: The variable @columns is been using elsewhere and it sets number of grids in a grid system. So it cannot be set as a string in a first place.

Comment: As far as I know, Less does not have any built in number to word conversion function. So if you want to replace like this you would have to write your own replace function which is kind of terrible if you have many such numbers to be converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming (as revealed in comments) you can't change the value of `@columns` variable itself and its possible values are not infinite, a trivial integer to string (or anything else) conversion table (a simple list) will do the trick:

```less
@columns: 12;
@columns-string: extract(@i2s, @columns);

// usage:
.class-@{columns-string} {
    /* ... */
}

// the table:
@i2s:
    one
    two
    three
    four
    five
    six
    seven
    eight
    nine
    ten
    eleven
    twelve
    thirteen
    fourteen
    fifteen
    sixteen
    seventeen
    eighteen
    nineteen
    twenty
    ;
```

Comment: Nice options but personally I would prefer to use the number itself in the class name instead of the conversion :)

Comment: @Harry, indeed I also wonder what could be a reason of using `.xxx-twelve` instead of `.xxx-12` (after all these number "codes" are invented centuries ago exactly to be used instead of those tedious words... :)

Comment: Nice solution indeed. 
In case you both still wonder I do prefer verbose expressions. So I don't end up with classes like .1-3-6-sm which have absolutely now meaning to me but are wildly used. So I guess it is just a personal preference.   
Thanks for the solution! Works great!

Comment: Speaking of `.1-3-6-sm`: `first-third-six(th?)-sm` does not look like making sense too... for a human readable stuff I'd prefer something like `.2nd-of-10` or so (assuming the use-case can't fit into fully semantic names like `.this-nice-chapter-left-column`).

Answer (score 0):

### The solution to this is to use array:

Instead of `@columns: 12`

I do `@columns: 12, twelfth`.

### Then I extract values:

```
@columns-number: extract(@columns, 1);
@columns-class: extract(@columns, 2);
```

The I can target value and a class name with mixin:

```
.@{columns-class} {
   .column(@columns-number);
}
```

Comment: Good that you have found a way to address your problem. Just for info, you can use Ctrl + K to format code blocks instead of `\``.